# How to solve $\sum _{k=1}^{n}{{4k^2-2}\over{4k^4+1}} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, telescopic-series

$$\sum _{k=1}^{n}{{4k^2-2}\over{4k^4+1}} $$

Now this appears to be a telescopic summation and I have reduced it to $\sum _{k=1}^{n}{{4k^2-2}\over(2k^2-2k+1)(2k^2+2k+1)}$ . But after this, I am unable to think of any other manipulation to make a telescopic form. Is this approach even correct or is it a dead end... Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint.**  We have the identity
$$\frac{4x^2-2}{4x^4+1}=\frac{2x-1}{2x^2-2x+1}-\frac{2x+1}{2x^2+2x+1}\,.$$

Comment: Can you add a bit more working please...??

Comment: This is just the standard partial fraction decomposition.  Since $$4x^4+1=(2x^2-2x+1)(2x^2+2x+1)\,,$$ the fraction $f(x):=\dfrac{4x^2-2}{4x^4+1}$ can be written as $$f(x)=\frac{ax+b}{2x^2-2x+1}+\frac{cx+d}{2x^2+2x+1}$$ for some constants $a,b,c,d$.  You can then solve for $a,b,c,d$.  One of the easiest relations to be found is $$a+c=0$$ (since $x\,f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to\infty$).  Putting $x:=0$ gives you $$b+d=-2\,.$$  Plugging in $x:=+1$, you get $$\dfrac{2}{5}=(a+b)+\dfrac{c+d}{5}\,.$$  Plugging in $x:=-1$, you also get $$\dfrac{2}{5}=\dfrac{b-a}{5}+(d-c)\,.$$

Answer (score 3):

We have
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\sum_{1\le k\le n}
\frac{4k^2-2}{(2k^2-2k+1)(2k^2+2k+1)}
\\
&\qquad=
2\sum_{1\le k\le n}
\left(
\frac{k^2}{2k^2-2k+1}
-
\frac{(k+1)^2}{2k^2+2k+1}
\right)
\\
&\qquad=
2\sum_{1\le k\le n}(f(k)-f(k+1))
\\
&\qquad=2(f(1)-f(n+1))
\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
where $f(k)=k^2/(2k^2-2k+1)$.

Comment: Nice Solutiins....